# Checkbox inside ng-template that is inside ng-popover is not accessible even though it is shown

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a checkbox inside a ng-template that is called by a ngbpopover. The checkbox is shown, but, I can't checked or unchecked the checkbox. But, it works when coded it in the stackblitz.

Stackblitz code - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ueruh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-triggers.html

```
<div class="container sr-get-your-text">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <!-- Page title -->
      <sr-title [value]="content.title"></sr-title>
      <!-- Reading name and author -->
      <div class="get-your-text-subtext" [innerHtml]="content.subText"></div>
      <div class="sr-path-selection">
        <button
          *ngFor="let option of options; trackBy : trackEntryItems"
          [attr.aria-label]="option.label"
          [value]="option.name.toLowerCase()"
          [innerText]="option.name"
          [ngClass]="{'sr-path-selected': option.selected}"
          [ngbPopover]="(option.name.toLowerCase() === 'anthology') && !showAgainCheck && popContent"
          placement="top"
          #popoverCheckbox="ngbPopover"
          (click)="onPathSelect(option)"></button>
      </div>
      <!-- Recommendation -->
      <div class="recommendation" [innerHtml]="content.recommendation"></div>
      <button srPrimaryButton
              *ngIf="isOptionSelected"
              [isButtonBar]="true"
              (click)="onContinue()">Continue
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #popContent>
  <form [formGroup]="showAgainForm" #frm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-check" (mouseleave)="onHoverOutside()">
      <input
        id="showAgain"
        formControlName="showAgainCheckBox"
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        [checked]="showAgainCheck"
        (click)="onChanged(frm)">
      <label for="showAgain" class="form-check-label">Show Again</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</ng-template>
```

expected to be able to check the checkbox.
Result is it's not accessible.

Comment: do you mean  it's not working locally but on stackbitz ?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha, yes

Comment: inspect and see if there is any overlay elements top if the checkbox.also try with another browser

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha, I did check with other browser. same result. Maybe, this has something to do with css. Because, when I remove a style tag "left: -9999px" in browser's editor, it works.